# Why Android refuses to create the file to write in?

Tags: java

Hello I try to create a file in android in java to write in and ti retrieve in to read inside it. But it failed, anyone can help me ?
This my my code.

```
public void saveAndRetrieve () {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sdcard + getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/scores.txt");
        writer.append("score: test");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,sdcard + getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/scores.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            Log.d("Test", "text : "+text+" : end");
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The exception i tried to repair is: .

> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.example.mathieu.whereswaldo-2/lib/x86 W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/data/user/0/com.example.mathieu.whereswaldo/files/scores.txt
>   (No such file or directory) W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:221)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:108)
>   W/System.err:     at java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:63)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.mathieu.whereswaldo.MainActivity.save(MainActivity.java:64)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.mathieu.whereswaldo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)

Comment: Have you added  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ?

Comment: Ah, yes, But it does not work !

Comment: your path is invalid , put this before buffered reader file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

Comment: But my exception is first at the second line of my code in "FileWriter writer = ..."

Comment: I have all the same exceptions after adding it

Comment: ok then put sdcard.getParentFile().mkdirs();  before it